# Check if array key equals certain value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have this array:

```
var arr = [
    ['First', 'lorem ipsum'],
    ['Second', 'dolor sit amet'],
];
```

and I want if `arr[0]` equals **First** do action 1, else do action 2.

I used:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var arr = markers[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        if(arr[0] == 'Lorem') {
                icon: 'http://imgur.com/1.png',
                }
        else {
            icon: 'http://imgur.com/2.png',
            }
    });

    var contentString = '';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

but I get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [.**

How should I do this?

Comment: can you post you full code, it seems like the error is not related to the code you posted.

Comment: Please read [ask] before asking questions

Comment: `if(arr[0][0] == 'First') {`

Comment: Sorry. I changed my code.

Comment: The posted code has several syntax errors. You can't use an `if` statement in an object literal.

Comment: @Vohuman is any way to obtain what I want?

Comment: `icon: (arr[0] === 'Lorem' ? 'http://imgur.com/1.png' : 'http://imgur.com/2.png')` -> [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `if` statement in an object literal. The code has several syntax errors.

You can define a variable that refers to the object and conditionally add the property to it:

```
var obj = {
   map: map
};

if ( condition ) {
   obj.icon = 'http://imgur.com/1.png';
} else {
   obj.icon = 'http://imgur.com/2.png';
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(obj);
```

Another option is using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: arr[0] == 'Lorem' ? 'http://imgur.com/1.png' : 'http://imgur.com/2.png'
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible with multiple if statements?

Comment: @wavix You are welcome. Yes, it is possible. I have updated the answer.